# One to many Mapping in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the below problem statement wherein there is something called as a material class which has to be mapped to a material.

There can be multiple material classes mapped to a single material. For example:

```
**Material Class**                     **Material**

  Washing Machine ------------------->  Appliances
  Fridge          ------------------->  Appliances
  Oven            ------------------->  Appliances
  Samsung         ------------------->  Mobile
  Nokia           ------------------->  Mobile
```

Also for my usecase there will be around 30000 material classes mapped to a couple of materials. From the UI I will be added material classes against a material and on clicking save that will be updated in the db. Edit, delete is also applicable from UI

I already have a collection called materials in my database and I have thought of about two approaches

- Embedded Document Pattern: **Approach 1**

```
  materials: [
  {
   _id: 'aaa'
   name: 'Appliances',
   classes: ['Washing Machine', 'Fridge', 'Oven'] // 10,000 entries
  },
  {
   _id: 'bbb'
   name: 'Mobile',
   classes: ['Samsung', 'Nokia'] // 5,000 entries 
  }
 ]
```

With the above approach, I can easily add, update(includes deletion as well) but the problem here will be the size of the array.

- Subset Pattern: **Approach 2**

Apart from the materials collection, I will have a new collection called material_classes which will be as follows

```
 material_classes: [
  {
   _id: 'ccc',
   material_id: 'aaa', // ObjectId of material entry which will act as mapping id
   name: 'Washing Machine'
  },
  {
   _id: 'ccc',
   material_id: 'Fridge',
   name: 'Washing Machine'
  },
  {
   _id: 'ddd',
   material_id: 'aaa',
   name: 'Washing Machine'
  },
  {
   _id: 'eee',
   material_id: 'aaa',
   name: 'Oven'
  },
  {
   _id: 'fff',
   material_id: 'bbb',
   name: 'Samsung'
  },
  {
   _id: 'ggg',
   material_id: 'bbb',
   name: 'Nokia'
  },
]
```

Now as per this pattern, I see we need to have 30000 entries in the material_classes collection also

- Creation of entries and updation of entries becomes complicated. More than that when a particular material is deleted from UI. I need to find and delete all the entries mapped to that material from the material_classes collection which is less performant.

So apart from above approaches, is there any better approach. If yes please suggest.
Else among the above which one would be a better option to pick.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my opinion, the 2nd Approach is better and i think the material `name` maybe need to be  `unique`. and the better way to handle your migration data, you could make a function to get all the data, and push to an Array then `insert/bulkwrite` to the new collection, would be better if using `transaction` for sure.

Comment: This is a new feature I am trying to implement therefore I have no requirement of migration here